# URI prefix is not recognized when using WebClient with Unity WebGL

Tags: webclient, unity-webgl

These code below will generate error "The URI prefix is not recognized", I already check the url,it's correct url format,it's my server url about upload function.

```
string url = "http://[skip]";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();      
byte[] result = wc.UploadData(url,"PUT", data);
```

Error result in Chrome Developer console is below:

```
NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
  at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri, System.Boolean useUriBase) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
Rethrow as WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Byte[] data, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

warning: 2 FS.syncfs operations in flight at once, probably just doing extra work
```

Unity version:2018.1.0b13

Build platform:WebGL

API Compatibility Level: .Net 4.x

Scripting Runtime Version:Stable(.Net 4.x Equivalent)